# Cannot find my azure endpoint for LogQueryClient

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I'm trying to access logs from my application insights from code via LogsQueryClient. In documentation I see that I would need endpoint to my azure monitor(which is logical) but I'm unable to find it in azure and when googling I had no luck finding what I need or at least didn't find something that would look to me like answer to my problem.
[This is constructor I believe I should use from documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y74kQ.png).

Any help would be kindly appreciated thanks.

Comment: Is your application insights connected to a Log Analytics workspace? Or is it a legacy deployment which is not yet backed by LAW? if so, connect it first

Comment: @silent yes my application insights are connected to workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need the workspaceId of your Log Analytics Workspace:

[image]

Then query like this:

```
logsQueryClient = new LogsQueryClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
var response = await logsQueryClient.QueryWorkspaceAsync("2c6892c2-6c05-49f8-a88c-********", "apprequests | take 10", new QueryTimeRange(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)));
```